# DRF: Serializer validation while submitting a POST request to detail route

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

DRF newbie here. I have the following model:

```
class User(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False)
```

I've managed to implement `POST /users/` successfully. I'm able to validate `password` and `email` fields in the request body against pre-defined constraints.(e.g. password cannot be entirely numeric) For this purpose, I override field validators such as `validate_password` and `validate_email`.

Now I'm trying to implement an endpoint `POST /users/pk/password/` through which users will be able to update their `password` resource. To achieve this I've used `detail_route`. Below you can find the corresponding implementation:

```
# Custom method to update the password resource of a given user.
@detail_route(methods=['post'])
def password(self, request, pk=None):

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # returns error
    else:

        password = request.data.get('password',None)
        new_password = request.data.get('new_password',None)

        if password and new_password:

            if check_password(password,user.password):

                # Use Django built-in to hash password.
                password_hash =  make_password(new_password)
                user.password = password_hash
                user.save()

                serializer_data = UserSerializer(user).data

                return Response(serializer_data)

            else:
                # return error reponse
        else:
            # return error response
```

By using this approach, I'm able to update the `password` field of a user but `validate_password` is not effective anymore when `POST /users/pk/password/` is called so that users can update their `password` with an entirely numeric one.

I'm aware of the fact that I can try to implement `validate_password` inside the detail route implementation, but it does not feel like the best way to go.

My question is what is the best way to do this without duplicating code and without moving validation logic into views.py?

PS: I cannot use nor extend Django User model for various reasons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This the problem, you are getting the data straight off the raw post, when you are supposed to be using the serializer

```
    password = request.data.get('password',None)
    new_password = request.data.get('new_password',None)
```

Now assuming your serializer with the validation code is called `MySerializer`, the above lines need to be replaced with something like

```
   serial = MySerializer(data=request.data)
   if serial.is_valid():
       password = serial.validated_data['password']
       new_password = serial.validated_data['new_password']
```

Now your validation code will be executed.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. But when I do this, I'm failing in serializer validation due to required fields such as email. Email is a required field to create users but it is not required when updating a password. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Don't be afraid to make multiple serializers. Lot's of newbies make that mistake. Make a new serializer for just the password field.